# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running webservice client

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, webservice-client

I'm getting the following error when I run a webservice client I've created using: eclipse, j2sdk1.4.2_13, axis1.0 and a WSDL file.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1655)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1262)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.findPublicStaticMethod(ClassUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:214)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.access$300(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder$1.run(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:148)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:111)
    at com.example.xmlns.SOAPEventSourceBindingStub.<init>(SOAPEventSourceBindingStub.java:27)
    at com.example.xmlns.SOAPEventSourceBindingStub.<init>(SOAPEventSourceBindingStub.java:17)
    at com.example.xmlns.Cliente.main(Cliente.java:16)
Exception in thread "main"
```

The client is doing this:
  `SOAPEventSourceBindingStub stub = new SOAPEventSourceBindingStub();`

```
public SOAPEventSourceBindingStub() throws org.apache.axis.AxisFault {
     this(null); (this is line 17)
}

public SOAPEventSourceBindingStub(java.net.URL endpointURL, javax.xml.rpc.Service service) throws org.apache.axis.AxisFault {
     this(service);
     super.cachedEndpoint = endpointURL;
}

public SOAPEventSourceBindingStub(javax.xml.rpc.Service service) throws org.apache.axis.AxisFault {
    if (service == null) {
        super.service = new org.apache.axis.client.Service(); (this is line 27)
    } else {
        super.service = service;
    }
        ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a library? Make sure all the libraries are in your classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the servlet Jar in your classpath or use a more recent version of axis.

> NOTE: AXIS 1.0 version even on client side needs servlet JAR file or you get this exception:
>    (upcoming 1.1 version should have this fixed)
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
>      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>      at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1613)
>      at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:1732)
>      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1219)
>      ...
> ```

---

**Resources :**

- [cvs commit :  xml-axis-wsif/java/lib/xerces2, xercesImpl_2_2_1.jar, xmlParserAPIs_2_2_1.jar](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/0F8SPnRDQZKSInZ97RLz)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with desktop application. In Netbeans this appeared suddenly, though I was changing only unrelated sql queries. Problematic packages were still in my main package, though couldn't be found.

Solved renaming problematic classes in my main package (and renaming back, if needed). Also corrected naming standard deviations (some class names first letters were low-case).